# Problems installing docker on raspberry pi 4B bullseye

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I'm trying to install docker on raspberry pi running Raspbian bullseye but I am running into a wall related to iptables. I have tried various methods mentioned at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/ but unfortunately they all return the same error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $  sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iptables : Depends: libip4tc2 (= 1.8.5-2) but 1.8.7-1 is to be installed
            Depends: libxtables12 (= 1.8.5-2) but 1.8.7-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried upgrading both `libip4tc2` but the error I get is that the latest version is installed.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade libip4tc2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libip4tc2 is already the newest version (1.8.7-1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the problem is that the dependency is for version `= 1.8.5-2` ... but you have a *later* version installed - though, that doesn't make sense since my install of docker works with `1.8.7-1`

Comment: There is no docker-ce in Raspberry Pi OS -Bullseye

Comment: @Milliways - there is if you add the `docker.com` repository

Comment: `you have held broken packages` - so don't hold them

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns no entries

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libip4tc2=1.8.5-2 libxtables12=1.8.5-2
```

seems to have done the trick. Thanks to Bravo for the tip in comments to the question.

Comment: seems odd that I have docker installed with version `1.8.7-1` of those packages ... perhaps the dependency problem has nothing to do with docker

Comment: what version of iptables do you have? (`apt-cache show iptables`)